# Using Coding Keys to exclude values from being decoded

Tags: swift, decodable

**I have the following structure to decode JSON data:**

**UPDATED:**

```
struct Section {
    let owner : String
    var items : [ValueVariables]
}

struct ValueVariables : Decodable {
    var isSelected = false
    let breed: String
    let color: String
    let tagNum: Int

    // other members 
}
```

**The issue is `isSelected` is not a value being decoded, how can I exclude it from being decoded to prevent it from causing an error like this:**

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "isSelected", intValue: nil),
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
>   0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: \"isSelected\", intValue: nil)
>   (\"isSelected\"), converted to is_selected.", underlyingError: nil))

**I have tried using coding keys like this, but it does not seem to work :**

```
private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case isSelected = "isSelected"
}
```

**Applied Answer:**

```
struct ValueVariables : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case breed, color, tagNum
    }

    var isSelected = false
    let breed: String
    let color: String
    let tagNum: Int
}
```

**The JSON Looks like this:**

```
[{"breed":"dog","color":"black","tagNum":20394}]
```

Error recieved:

> Type 'ValueVariables' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Comment: isSelected is a computed var? Is it a var for UI? Then don't mix like that your "data model" and a ui-model. Is it an addon?

Comment: Your latest version of the posted code does _not_ generate an error. If your own code is different and generates an error you need to tell us but to me this question has been already correctly answered.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other way round, you have to specify all keys which are going to be decoded.

```
struct ValueVariables : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case breed, color
    }

    var isSelected = false
    let breed: String
    let color: String
}
```

Comment: In addition to case `isSelected = "isSelected"`?

Comment: No, **omit** the excluded keys

Comment: What if color is a Int not a String, how would the CodingKeys be different?

Comment: `color` is always a string even if the **value** is `Int`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, the Coding Keys do not seem to help

Comment: Is there something I need to change in `struct ValueVariables : Decodable {` ?

Comment: I updated the answer. The JSON `{"breed":"dog","color":"black"}` will be decoded correctly.

Comment: Now I get the error: `Type 'ValueVariable' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **entire** struct.

Comment: You have to add `tagNum` to the CodingKeys. Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: `tagNum` is in the CodingKeys I was just shortening the struct for the question, please see the update I posted with the full struct and JSON. I still get the error does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Comment: That's impossible if you decode `JSONDecoder().decode([ValueVariables].self, from:...`

Comment: I believe I am doing it correctly as the following: `try decoder.decode([ValueVariables].self` please see my update

Comment: The struct, the code and the JSON in the question do work.